# Invoking a javascript function with string arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, syntax-error

I've recently encountered an error while trying to run a function with more than one argument.

```
<button type = "button" id = "clickmepls" onclick = killButton("clickmepls", "grave1")> Click me please </button>
```

The function's definition is the following:

```
function killButton(buttonname, graveID){
   /* some code */
}
```

When the script is run, I'm given the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWpvO.png

It happens whenever there is more than one argument in the function - the first one is shown in the error window, the arrow always points at what (doesn't) come after.

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot quotes.

```
<button type = "button" id = "clickmepls" onclick = "killButton('clickmepls', 'grave1');"> Click me please </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute values with spaces in them must be quoted, otherwise the space terminates the attribute value in the middle of the JavaScript statement.

```
onclick="killButton('clickmepls', etc… "
```